# trying out "win32com.client" but it cannot find my file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to modify some excel document but it doesn't actualize the calculated cells inside that document. It seems I must open the document with excel. I found [this link](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/open-refresh-connections-save-and-close-excel-file/m-p/353832).

But it fails finding my document. How is that possible? Could someone help on that specific point please?

Here is what I get:

```
>>> os.listdir()
['R_F.xlsx']
>>> import win32com.client
>>> xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
>>> wb = xl.workbooks.open("R_F.xlsx")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Une exception s’est produite.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Désolé... Nous ne trouvons pas R_F.xlsx. Peut-être l'avez-vous déplacé, renommé ou supprimé\xa0?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)`
```

Same does happen when trying to open a word document. It doesn't find it! Very strange.

Comment: Try passing a full pathname to the file - `os.path.abspath()` may help here.  A bare filename is going to be looked for in the current working directory, but there's no reason for Excel's CWD to be the same as your program's CWD.

Comment: So many thanks to you ! It works. I'm not sure why relative path shoudn't work, but I'll avoid them. I've been struggling all the afternoon with that. Thanks again.